# How to diagnose Graph permission issues with Contact and Calendar resources

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Having issues accessing graph resources for a specific user. Most have no issues. This specific user authenticates with our client via their school Outlook account which I am assuming is where the issue lies.

Our service attempts to create a specific folder using the `/me/contactFolders` endpoint. When we make the post, we get the error that `the resource could not be discovered`. Digging in a bit, I decided to login with their account to the Graph explorer and could not query endpoints such as, `/me/contacts`, `/me/contactFolders`, `/me/events`, etc.. None of the examples provided worked to fetch any data. I am assuming this has to do with permissioning of the users account, but I am not sure what permissions they would need to access both calendars and contacts (we are setting scopes and delegated permissions correctly as this problem is only associated with a couple users).

This is the error message that I received when trying to query graph:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5cfd7b28-a915-42cf-9bce-a8a2509c3f1f",
            "date": "2018-12-20T18:48:34"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help in diagnosing this issue would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure they have an Exchange license and a provisioned mailbox?

Comment: I am not. Unfortunately we have no way to contact the administer of the account. What I am hoping to gain is if someone runs into this same issue, I will be able to let the user know what they need to ask of their administrator.  Are there specific permissions that need to be active in order to query graph for their school account?

Comment: What kind of authentication are you trying to use? You could take the users access token and compare it to a working access token. Microsoft made a great website to see the information in the tokens, see [https://jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms)

Comment: @Stephan We are using OAuth2.0 through the Azure AD v2 endpoint. Tried decoding the token, but it's not in the valid format (assuming different hashing algorithm). Doesn't look like the information that it provides is of much help either.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't decode the token then you're most likely facing one of the following issues:

1. You obtained the token incorrectly
2. You're attempting to decode the Authorization Code rather than the Access Token (i.e. the string you get from 1st OAuth step rather than the 2nd).
3. The token is for Microsoft Account (a.k.a. MSA, lesser aka as an Xbox or Outlook.com account).

You can only decode tokens issued by Azure AD (AAD).  School accounts (i.e. those ending in `.edu`) are basically the same as Work accounts, they're owned and managed by an Azure Active Directory.

In terms of checking which services are provisioned for the current User, you can obtain these from the `/me` endpoint so long as you have requested either the `User.Read` or `User.ReadWrite` scope. Note that this information isn't included by default so you'll need to specifically request the `provisionedPlans`. For example, the following query will return the current user's `id`, `userPrincipalName`, and their list of `provisionedPlans` (i.e. services):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=id,userPrincipalName,provisionedPlans
```

The results are pretty self-explanatory but in your particular case you're looking for a service named `exchange` (there are often more than one but they should all reflect the same status):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,userPrincipalName,provisionedPlans)/$entity",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "provisionedPlans": [
        {
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "provisioningStatus": "Success",
            "service": "exchange"
        },
```